# Publish WordPress draft pages in bulk

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am working on a site where i created 100k wordpress pages through WP CSV plugin. However around 60k pages were kept in draft.

How can I publish these pages in bulk?

If I try to change to 'post_status' from database directly, the permalink of the page is kept as empty and redirect to homepage.

Also if I try to increase the number of item per page and then bulk publish; in this case the limit is only kept to minimum 400 and it takes too much time in processing 400 too.

Is there any optimized solution for this?

Comment: Check this out: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12512/how-to-update-page-status-from-publish-to-draft-and-draft-to-publish

Comment: yes but this simply updates 'post_status' which results in publishing the post but the permalink is kept empty. I need to call proper wordpress publish function. in that case the page permalink will also be generated.

Comment: You can pass the `slug` as an argument to `wp_update_post`. You can create the slug based on the title. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_post/

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't have shell access (SSH) to your host and are unable to further increase the `max_execution_time` for PHP, you can do the following.
Create a PHP file, e.g. `bulk_publish.php` in your WP root directory, containing the following code:

```
<?php

require_once('./wp-load.php');

$post_type = 'page'; // Change, if you need to handle another post type
$posts_per_page = 400; // if this is too much, reduce it

$posts = get_posts([
  'post_type' => $post_type,
  'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
  'post_status' => ['draft'],
  'lang' => '',
]);

if (count($posts) > 0) {
  foreach ($posts as $post) {
    wp_update_post([
      'ID' => $post->ID,
      'post_status' => 'publish',
    ]);
  }
  wp_redirect('/bulk_publish.php');
} else {
  echo "Done.";
}
```

This will publish `$posts_per_page` pages at a time, iterating over `draft` status posts, then redirect back to `bulk_publish.php`. This will make sure you avoid hitting the `max_execution_time`. You can experiment with increasing this number. If you need to process 60k pages, your browser will complain about too many redirects at some point. In this case, just refresh once at let it do the next couple of iterations until it complains again. Once it outputs "Done.", you're done.

Afterwards, delete the `bulk_publish.php` file off the server.